# Can't get module to rewrite a 3rd party module's block

Tags: overrides

I would like to rewrite a block in a 3rd party module and have tried creating my own module to achieve this with class rewrites.

My module is called **Creed_CustomMenu** and the module name of the module whose block I am trying to rewrite is called **Wp_CustomMenu**.

I thought I had it coded corectly but when I place a break point on PatentStorm on my class none it doesn't break in my class rewrite and none of my changes take effect.

Here is my Code for the **Creed_CustomMenu** module

*app/etc/modules/Creed_CustomMenu.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Creed_CustomMenu>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <WP_CustomMenu />
            </depends>
        </Creed_CustomMenu>
    </modules>
</config>
```

*app/code/local/Creed/CustomMenu/etc/config.xml*

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Creed_CustomMenu>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Creed_CustomMenu>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <custommenu>
                <rewrite>
                    <navigation>Creed_CustomMenu_Block_Navigation</navigation>
                </rewrite>
            </custommenu>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

*app/code/local/Creed/CustomMenu/Block/Navigation.php*

```
<?php

class Creed_CustomMenu_Block_Navigation extends WP_CustomMenu_Block_Navigation
{
    public function drawCustomMenuItem($category, $level = 0, $last = false)
    {
        if (!$category->getIsActive()) return '';
        $html = array();
        $id = $category->getId();
        // --- Static Block ---
        $blockId = sprintf(self::CUSTOM_BLOCK_TEMPLATE, $id); // --- static block key
        #Mage::log($blockId);
        $collection = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('identifier', array('like' => $blockId . '%'))
            ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);
        $blockId = $collection->getFirstItem()->getIdentifier();
        #Mage::log($blockId);
        $blockHtml = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($blockId)->toHtml();
        // --- Sub Categories ---
        $activeChildren = $this->_getActiveChildren($category, $level);
        // --- class for active category ---
        $active = ''; if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)) $active = ' act';
        // --- Popup functions for show ---
        $wideBlock = false;  // CB: added new condition for setting extra wide static blocks
        if (strpos($blockId,'wide') !== false) {
            $wideBlock = true;
        }
        $drawPopup = ($blockHtml || count($activeChildren));
        if ($drawPopup) {
            $html[] = '<div id="menu' . $id . '" class="menu' . $active . '" onmouseover="wpShowMenuPopup(this, event, \'popup' . $id . '\');" onmouseout="wpHideMenuPopup(this, event, \'popup' . $id . '\', \'menu' . $id . '\')">';
        } else {
            $html[] = '<div id="menu' . $id . '" class="menu' . $active . '">';
        }
        // --- Top Menu Item ---
        $html[] = '<div class="parentMenu">';
        if ($level == 0 && $drawPopup) {
            $html[] = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'">';
        } else {
            $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'">';
        }
        $name = $this->escapeHtml($category->getName());
        if (Mage::getStoreConfig('custom_menu/general/non_breaking_space')) {
            $name = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $name);
        }
        $html[] = '<span>' . $name . '</span>';
        $html[] = '</a>';
        $html[] = '</div>';
        $html[] = '</div>';
        // --- Add Popup block (hidden) ---
        if ($drawPopup) {
            // --- Popup function for hide ---
            $html[] = '<div id="popup' . $id . '" class="wp-custom-menu-popup" onmouseout="wpHideMenuPopup(this, event, \'popup' . $id . '\', \'menu' . $id . '\')" onmouseover="wpPopupOver(this, event, \'popup' . $id . '\', \'menu' . $id . '\')">';
            // --- draw Sub Categories ---
            if ($blockHtml)
            {
            if (count($activeChildren))
            {
                if ($wideBlock) {
                    $html[] = '<div class="block1 grid12-2">';
                } else{
                    $html[] = '<div class="block1 grid12-7">';
                }
                $html[] = $this->drawColumns($activeChildren);
                $html[] = '<div class="clearBoth"></div>';
                $html[] = '</div>';
            }

            // --- draw Custom User Block ---
                if ($wideBlock) {
                    $html[] = '<div id="' . $blockId . '" class="block2 grid12-10">';
                } else{
                    $html[] = '<div id="' . $blockId . '" class="block2 grid12-5">';
                }
                $html[] = $blockHtml;
                $html[] = '</div>';

            }
            else
                if (count($activeChildren)) {
                    $html[] = '<div class="block1 grid-full">';
                    $html[] = $this->drawColumns($activeChildren);
                    $html[] = '<div class="clearBoth"></div>';
                    $html[] = '</div>';
                }
            $html[] = '</div>';
        }
        $html = implode("\n", $html);
        return $html;
    }
}
```

And here is my Code for the **WP_CustomMenu** module I'm trying to rewrite
*app/code/local/WP/CustomMenu/etc/config.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <WP_CustomMenu>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </WP_CustomMenu>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <custommenu>
                    <file>webandpeople/custommenu.xml</file>
                </custommenu>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <custom_menu translate="title" module="custommenu">
                                            <title><![CDATA[Web & People: Custom Menu]]></title>
                                            <sort_order>2000</sort_order>
                                        </custom_menu>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <navigation>WP_CustomMenu_Block_Navigation</navigation>
                    <!-- v1.4-1.6 -->
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
            <page>
                <rewrite>
                    <html_topmenu>WP_CustomMenu_Block_Topmenu</html_topmenu>
                    <!-- v1.7 -->
                </rewrite>
            </page>
            <custommenu>
                <class>WP_CustomMenu_Block</class>
            </custommenu>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <custommenu>
                <class>WP_CustomMenu_Helper</class>
            </custommenu>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <default>
        <custom_menu>
            <general>
                <enabled>1</enabled>
                <display_empty_categories>1</display_empty_categories>
                <max_level>3</max_level>
                <show_home_link>1</show_home_link>
                <non_breaking_space>0</non_breaking_space>
                <ie6_ignore>1</ie6_ignore>
                <rtl>0</rtl>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
            </general>
            <columns>
                <count>3</count>
                <divided_horizontally>0</divided_horizontally>
                <integrate>1</integrate>
            </columns>
            <popup>
                <width>0</width>
                <top_offset>0</top_offset>
                <delay_displaying>0</delay_displaying>
                <delay_hiding>0</delay_hiding>
            </popup>
        </custom_menu>
    </default>
    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <about_webandpeople translate="title" module="custommenu">
                                            <title><![CDATA[Web & People: About Us]]></title>
                                            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                                        </about_webandpeople>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

*app/code/local/WP/CustomMenu/Block/Navigation.php*

```
<?php
```

class WP_CustomMenu_Block_Navigation extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation
{
    const CUSTOM_BLOCK_TEMPLATE = "wp_custom_menu_%d";

```
private $_productsCount = null;

public function showHomeLink()
{
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('custom_menu/general/show_home_link');
}

public function drawCustomMenuItem($category, $level = 0, $last = false)
{
    if (!$category->getIsActive()) return '';
    $html = array();
    $id = $category->getId();
    // --- Static Block ---
    $blockId = sprintf(self::CUSTOM_BLOCK_TEMPLATE, $id); // --- static block key
    #Mage::log($blockId);
    $collection = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('identifier', array('like' => $blockId . '%'))
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);
    $blockId = $collection->getFirstItem()->getIdentifier();
    #Mage::log($blockId);
    $blockHtml = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($blockId)->toHtml();
    // --- Sub Categories ---
    $activeChildren = $this->_getActiveChildren($category, $level);
    // --- class for active category ---
    $active = ''; if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)) $active = ' act';
    // --- Popup functions for show ---
    $drawPopup = ($blockHtml || count($activeChildren));
    if ($drawPopup) {
        $html[] = '<div id="menu' . $id . '" class="menu' . $active . '" onmouseover="wpShowMenuPopup(this, event, \'popup' . $id . '\');" onmouseout="wpHideMenuPopup(this, event, \'popup' . $id . '\', \'menu' . $id . '\')">';
    } else {
        $html[] = '<div id="menu' . $id . '" class="menu' . $active . '">';
    }
    // --- Top Menu Item ---
    $html[] = '<div class="parentMenu">';
    if ($level == 0 && $drawPopup) {
        $html[] = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'">';
    } else {
        $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'">';
    }
    $name = $this->escapeHtml($category->getName());
    if (Mage::getStoreConfig('custom_menu/general/non_breaking_space')) {
        $name = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $name);
    }
    $html[] = '<span>' . $name . '</span>';
    $html[] = '</a>';
    $html[] = '</div>';
    $html[] = '</div>';
    // --- Add Popup block (hidden) ---
    if ($drawPopup) {
        // --- Popup function for hide ---
        $html[] = '<div id="popup' . $id . '" class="wp-custom-menu-popup" onmouseout="wpHideMenuPopup(this, event, \'popup' . $id . '\', \'menu' . $id . '\')" onmouseover="wpPopupOver(this, event, \'popup' . $id . '\', \'menu' . $id . '\')">';
        // --- draw Sub Categories ---
        if ($blockHtml)
        {
        if (count($activeChildren))
        {
            $html[] = '<div class="block1 grid12-7">';
            $html[] = $this->drawColumns($activeChildren);
            $html[] = '<div class="clearBoth"></div>';
            $html[] = '</div>';
        }

        // --- draw Custom User Block ---

            $html[] = '<div id="' . $blockId . '" class="block2 grid12-5">';
            $html[] = $blockHtml;
            $html[] = '</div>';

        }
        else
            if (count($activeChildren)) {
                $html[] = '<div class="block1 grid-full">';
                $html[] = $this->drawColumns($activeChildren);
                $html[] = '<div class="clearBoth"></div>';
                $html[] = '</div>';
            }
        $html[] = '</div>';
    }
    $html = implode("\n", $html);
    return $html;
}

public function drawMenuItem($children, $level = 1)
{
    $html = '<div class="itemMenu level' . $level . '">';
    $keyCurrent = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
    foreach ($children as $child)
    {
        if (is_object($child) && $child->getIsActive())
        {
            // --- class for active category ---
            $active = '';
            if ($this->isCategoryActive($child))
            {
                $active = ' actParent';
                if ($child->getId() == $keyCurrent) $active = ' act';
            }
            // --- format category name ---
            $name = $this->escapeHtml($child->getName());
            if (Mage::getStoreConfig('custom_menu/general/non_breaking_space'))
                $name = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $name);
            $html.= '<a class="itemMenuName level' . $level . $active . '" href="' . $this->getCategoryUrl($child) . '"><span>' . $name . '</span></a>';
            $activeChildren = $this->_getActiveChildren($child, $level);
            if (count($activeChildren) > 0)
            {
                $html.= '<div class="itemSubMenu level' . $level . '">';
                $html.= $this->drawMenuItem($activeChildren, $level + 1);
                $html.= '</div>';
            }
        }
    }
    $html.= '</div>';
    return $html;
}

public function drawColumns($children)
{
    $html = '';
    // --- explode by columns ---
    $columns = (int)Mage::getStoreConfig('custom_menu/columns/count');
    if ($columns < 1) $columns = 1;
    $chunks = $this->_explodeByColumns($children, $columns);
    // --- draw columns ---
    $lastColumnNumber = count($chunks);
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($chunks as $key => $value)
    {
        if (!count($value)) continue;
        $class = '';
        if ($i == 1) $class.= ' first';
        if ($i == $lastColumnNumber) $class.= ' last';
        if ($i % 2) $class.= ' odd'; else $class.= ' even';
        $html.= '<div class="column' . $class . '">';
        $html.= $this->drawMenuItem($value, 1);
        $html.= '</div>';
        $i++;
    }
    return $html;
}

protected function _getActiveChildren($parent, $level)
{
    $activeChildren = array();
    // --- check level ---
    $maxLevel = (int)Mage::getStoreConfig('custom_menu/general/max_level');
    if ($maxLevel > 0)
    {
        if ($level >= ($maxLevel - 1)) return $activeChildren;
    }
    // --- / check level ---
    if (Mage::helper('catalog/category_flat')->isEnabled())
    {
        $children = $parent->getChildrenNodes();
        $childrenCount = count($children);
    }
    else
    {
        $children = $parent->getChildren();
        $childrenCount = $children->count();
    }
    $hasChildren = $children && $childrenCount;
    if ($hasChildren)
    {
        foreach ($children as $child)
        {
            if ($this->_isCategoryDisplayed($child))
            {
                array_push($activeChildren, $child);
            }
        }
    }
    return $activeChildren;
}

private function _isCategoryDisplayed(&$child)
{
    if (!$child->getIsActive()) return false;
    // === check products count ===
    // --- get collection info ---
    if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('custom_menu/general/display_empty_categories'))
    {
        $data = $this->_getProductsCountData();
        // --- check by id ---
        $id = $child->getId();
        #Mage::log($id); Mage::log($data);
        if (!isset($data[$id]) || !$data[$id]['product_count']) return false;
    }
    // === / check products count ===
    return true;
}

private function _getProductsCountData()
{
    if (is_null($this->_productsCount))
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Collection */
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('is_active')
            ->setProductStoreId($storeId)
            ->setLoadProductCount(true)
            ->setStoreId($storeId);
        $productsCount = array();
        foreach($collection as $cat)
        {
            $productsCount[$cat->getId()] = array(
                'name' => $cat->getName(),
                'product_count' => $cat->getProductCount(),
            );
        }
        #Mage::log($productsCount);
        $this->_productsCount = $productsCount;
    }
    return $this->_productsCount;
}

private function _explodeByColumns($target, $num)
{
    if ((int)Mage::getStoreConfig('custom_menu/columns/divided_horizontally')) {
        $target = self::_explodeArrayByColumnsHorisontal($target, $num);
    } else {
        $target = self::_explodeArrayByColumnsVertical($target, $num);
    }
    #return $target;
    if ((int)Mage::getStoreConfig('custom_menu/columns/integrate') && count($target))
    {
        // --- combine consistently numerically small column ---
        // --- 1. calc length of each column ---
        $max = 0; $columnsLength = array();
        foreach ($target as $key => $child)
        {
            $count = 0;
            $this->_countChild($child, 1, $count);
            if ($max < $count) $max = $count;
            $columnsLength[$key] = $count;
        }
        // --- 2. merge small columns with next ---
        $xColumns = array(); $column = array(); $cnt = 0;
        $xColumnsLength = array(); $k = 0;
        foreach ($columnsLength as $key => $count)
        {
            $cnt+= $count;
            if ($cnt > $max && count($column))
            {
                $xColumns[$k] = $column;
                $xColumnsLength[$k] = $cnt - $count;
                $k++; $column = array(); $cnt = $count;
            }
            $column = array_merge($column, $target[$key]);
        }
        $xColumns[$k] = $column;
        $xColumnsLength[$k] = $cnt - $count;
        // --- 3. integrate columns of one element ---
        $target = $xColumns; $xColumns = array(); $nextKey = -1;
        if ($max > 1 && count($target) > 1)
        {
            foreach($target as $key => $column)
            {
                if ($key == $nextKey) continue;
                if ($xColumnsLength[$key] == 1)
                {
                    // --- merge with next column ---
                    $nextKey = $key + 1;
                    if (isset($target[$nextKey]) && count($target[$nextKey]))
                    {
                        $xColumns[] = array_merge($column, $target[$nextKey]);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                $xColumns[] = $column;
            }
            $target = $xColumns;
        }
    }
    $_rtl = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('custom_menu/general/rtl');
    if ($_rtl) {
        $target = array_reverse($target);
    }
    return $target;
}

private function _countChild($children, $level, &$count)
{
    foreach ($children as $child)
    {
        if ($child->getIsActive())
        {
            $count++; $activeChildren = $this->_getActiveChildren($child, $level);
            if (count($activeChildren) > 0) $this->_countChild($activeChildren, $level + 1, $count);
        }
    }
}

private static function _explodeArrayByColumnsHorisontal($list, $num)
{
    if ($num <= 0) return array($list);
    $partition = array();
    $partition = array_pad($partition, $num, array());
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
        $partition[$i][$key] = $value;
        if (++$i == $num) $i = 0;
    }
    return $partition;
}

private static function _explodeArrayByColumnsVertical($list, $num)
{
    if ($num <= 0) return array($list);
    $listlen = count($list);
    $partlen = floor($listlen / $num);
    $partrem = $listlen % $num;
    $partition = array();
    $mark = 0;
    for ($column = 0; $column < $num; $column++) {
        $incr = ($column < $partrem) ? $partlen + 1 : $partlen;
        $partition[$column] = array_slice($list, $mark, $incr);
        $mark += $incr;
    }
    return $partition;
}


/**
 * Render category to html
 *
 * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category
 * @param int Nesting level number
 * @param boolean Whether ot not this item is last, affects list item class
 * @param boolean Whether ot not this item is first, affects list item class
 * @param boolean Whether ot not this item is outermost, affects list item class
 * @param string Extra class of outermost list items
 * @param string If specified wraps children list in div with this class
 * @param boolean Whether ot not to add on* attributes to list item
 * @return string
 */
protected function _renderCategoryMenuItemHtml($category, $level = 0, $isLast = false, $isFirst = false,
                                               $isOutermost = false, $outermostItemClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '', $noEventAttributes = false)
{
    if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
        return '';
    }
    $html = array();

    // get all children
    if (Mage::helper('catalog/category_flat')->isEnabled()) {
        $children = (array)$category->getChildrenNodes();
        $childrenCount = count($children);
    } else {
        $children = $category->getChildren();
        $childrenCount = $children->count();
    }
    $hasChildren = ($children && $childrenCount);

    // select active children
    $activeChildren = array();
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        if ($child->getIsActive()) {
            $activeChildren[] = $child;
        }
    }
    $activeChildrenCount = count($activeChildren);
    $hasActiveChildren = ($activeChildrenCount > 0);

    // prepare list item html classes
    $classes = array();
    $classes[] = 'level' . $level;
    $classes[] = 'nav-' . $this->_getItemPosition($level);
    if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)) {
        $classes[] = 'active';
    }
    $linkClass = '';
    if ($isOutermost && $outermostItemClass) {
        $classes[] = $outermostItemClass;
        $linkClass = ' class="'.$outermostItemClass.'"';
    }
    if ($isFirst) {
        $classes[] = 'first';
    }
    if ($isLast) {
        $classes[] = 'last';
    }
    if ($hasActiveChildren) {
        $classes[] = 'parent';
    }

    //NEW: add special class if level == 1 and menu is not an accordion.
    if ($this->_isAccordion == FALSE && $level == 1) {
        $classes[] = 'item';
    }

    // prepare list item attributes
    $attributes = array();
    if (count($classes) > 0) {
        $attributes['class'] = implode(' ', $classes);
    }
    if ($hasActiveChildren && !$noEventAttributes) {
        $attributes['onmouseover'] = 'toggleMenu(this,1)';
        $attributes['onmouseout'] = 'toggleMenu(this,0)';
    }

    // assemble list item with attributes
    $htmlLi = '<li';
    foreach ($attributes as $attrName => $attrValue) {
        $htmlLi .= ' ' . $attrName . '="' . str_replace('"', '\"', $attrValue) . '"';
    }
    $htmlLi .= '>';
    $html[] = $htmlLi;

    $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
    $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
    $html[] = '</a>';

    // render children
    $htmlChildren = '';
    $j = 0;
    foreach ($activeChildren as $child) {
        $htmlChildren .= $this->_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml(
            $child,
            ($level + 1),
            ($j == $activeChildrenCount - 1),
            ($j == 0),
            false,
            $outermostItemClass,
            $childrenWrapClass,
            $noEventAttributes
        );
        $j++;
    }
    if (!empty($htmlChildren)) {

        //NEW: add opener if menu is used as accordion.
        if ($this->_isAccordion == TRUE)
            $html[] = '<span class="opener">&nbsp;</span>';

        if ($childrenWrapClass) {
            $html[] = '<div class="' . $childrenWrapClass . '">';
        }
        $html[] = '<ul class="level' . $level . '">';
        $html[] = $htmlChildren;
        $html[] = '</ul>';
        if ($childrenWrapClass) {
            $html[] = '</div>';
        }
    }

    $html[] = '</li>';

    $html = implode("\n", $html);
    return $html;
}




/**
 * Get catagories of current store
 *
 * @return Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection
 */
public function getStoreCategories()
{
    $helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
    return $helper->getStoreCategories();
}


/**
 * Render categories menu in HTML
 *
 * @param bool Add opener if menu is used as accordion.
 * @param int Level number for list item class to start from
 * @param string Extra class of outermost list items
 * @param string If specified wraps children list in div with this class
 * @return string
 */
public function renderCategoriesMenuHtml($isAccordion = FALSE, $level = 0, $outermostItemClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '')
{
    //NEW: save additional attribute
    $this->_isAccordion = $isAccordion;

    $activeCategories = array();
    foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $child) {
        if ($child->getIsActive()) {
            $activeCategories[] = $child;
        }
    }
    $activeCategoriesCount = count($activeCategories);
    $hasActiveCategoriesCount = ($activeCategoriesCount > 0);

    if (!$hasActiveCategoriesCount) {
        return '';
    }

    $html = '';
    $j = 0;
    foreach ($activeCategories as $category) {
        $html .= $this->_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml(
            $category,
            $level,
            ($j == $activeCategoriesCount - 1),
            ($j == 0),
            true,
            $outermostItemClass,
            $childrenWrapClass,
            true
        );
        $j++;
    }

    return $html;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out what was causing the issue.

The `WP/CustomMenu/Block/Topmenu.php` block was the object being called from the template file.  It was itself extending the `WP/CustomMenu/Block/Navigation.php` class which is why my rewrite was not working.

*WP/CustomMenu/Block/Topmenu.php*

```
<?php

if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('custom_menu/general/enabled') ||
   (Mage::getStoreConfig('custom_menu/general/ie6_ignore') && Mage::helper('custommenu')->isIE6()))
{
    class WP_CustomMenu_Block_Topmenu extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu
    {

    }
    return;
}

class WP_CustomMenu_Block_Topmenu extends WP_CustomMenu_Block_Navigation
{

}
```

The **solution** was to rewrite the *WP/CustomMenu/Block/Topmenu.php* also.   Then it finally worked.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
   <blocks>
        <custommenu>
            <rewrite>
                <navigation>Creed_CustomMenu_Block_Navigation</navigation>
            </rewrite>
        </custommenu>
    </blocks>
```

With

```
    <blocks>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <navigation>Creed_CustomMenu_Block_Navigation</navigation>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </blocks>
```

in your new module.
This is needed because the block `WP_CustomMenu_Block_Navigation` is not instantiated using `createBlock('custommenu/navigation')`. It is instantiated using `createBlock('catalog/navigation')`...because it rewrites the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` block.

**[Edit]**
And in the `app/etc/modules/Creed_CustomMenu.xml` file make your extension depend on the  `WP_CustomMenu` extension. This way it will be loaded after it.

Comment: thanks but that didn't work.  I tried that before too as I saw that was how WP_CustomMenu rewrote the class in their config.xml

Comment: @CreedBratton/ See my update. I forgot about that.

Comment: I have that in already.  Does it look correct to you? I put the code in my question.

Comment: do you think if could have something to do with the module I'm trying to overwrite also being in the local code pool?

Comment: The codepool has nothing to do with it. Also, a a quick look, what you did seams ok. I'm puzzled.

Comment: I finally figured it out, see my answer below.  I'd be interested in what you think.  Interestingly, this actually led to another issue for me, I posted another question on that [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/45978/6549).